New Heegaard diagram after surgery on 3-manifolds
I am trying to figure out how to obtain a Heegaard decomposition (diagram) after surgering a 3-manifold by a knot which is embedded in the Heegaard surface. I know that the result of surgery will end up adding a 2-handle to each handlebody, where one of the attaching circles is the knot. This adds genus to the Heegaard surface, and it appears we are almost done, except that the knot attaching circle may intersect with Heegaard circles for its own handlebody.
I have tried to find literature about resolving these intersections or about obtaining these new Heegaard diagrams combinatorially, but to no avail. Any possible avenues of thought would be very helpful!
